# Parsing JSON web scraper output

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am practicing web scraping using the requests and BeautifulSoup modules on the following website:

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080684/

My code thus far properly outputs the json in question. I'd like help in extracting from the json only the `name` and `description` into a response dictionary.

**Code**

```
# Send HTTP requests
import requests

import json

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class WebScraper:

    def send_http_request():

        # Obtain the URL via user input
        url = input('Input the URL:\n')

        # Get the webpage
        r = requests.get(url)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

        # Check response object's status code
        if r:
            p = json.loads("".join(soup.find('script', {'type':'application/ld+json'}).contents))
            print(p)
        else:
            print('\nInvalid movie page!')


WebScraper.send_http_request()
```

**Desired Output**

```
{"title": "Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back", "description": "After the Rebels are brutally overpowered by the Empire on the ice planet Hoth, Luke Skywalker begins Jedi training with Yoda, while his friends are pursued by Darth Vader and a bounty hunter named Boba Fett all over the galaxy."}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the dictonary and then print a new JSON object using the `dumps` method:

```
# Send HTTP requests
import requests

import json

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class WebScraper:

    def send_http_request():

        # Obtain the URL via user input
        url = input('Input the URL:\n')

        # Get the webpage
        r = requests.get(url)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

        # Check response object's status code
        if r:
            p = json.loads("".join(soup.find('script', {'type':'application/ld+json'}).contents))
            output = json.dumps({"title": p["name"], "description": p["description"]})
            print(output)
        else:
            print('\nInvalid movie page!')


WebScraper.send_http_request()
```

Output:

```
{"title": "Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back", "description": "Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back is a movie starring Mark Hamill, Harrison Ford, and Carrie Fisher. After the Rebels are brutally overpowered by the Empire on the ice planet Hoth, Luke Skywalker begins Jedi training..."}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create a new dictionary from `p` given 2 keys `name` and `description`.

```
        # Check response object's status code
        if r:
            p = json.loads("".join(soup.find('script', {'type':'application/ld+json'}).contents))
            desired_output = {"title": p["name"], "description": p["description"]}
            print(desired_output)
        else:
            print('\nInvalid movie page!')
```

Output:

```
{'title': 'Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back', 'description': 'Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back is a movie starring Mark Hamill, Harrison Ford, and Carrie Fisher. After the Rebels are brutally overpowered by the Empire on the ice planet Hoth, Luke Skywalker begins Jedi training...'}
```

Comment: `p` is already type `dict` so there is no need to use the `dict()` function!

Comment: Updated. Thanks!